# JDBC prepared statement creates one extra database hit without any params

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jdbc, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have one annoying issue and i can not figure out why it is happening. To give you short introduction, i implemented batch processing (batch insert) using MySql and JDBC template on my Spring Boot project.

So basically batch insert is working like it should, and performance is really amazing, BUT there is this one small issue that really is annoying and it causes constraint exception when i am inserting in one table that has unique key on two columns (id, value).

So i have this code:

```
private String INSERT_SQL_PARAMS = "INSERT INTO item_params(p_key, p_value, item_id) values (?,?,?)"

override fun saveParams(configParams: Set<ItemParam>) {
    jdbcTemplate!!.update { connection ->
        connection.autoCommit = false
        val ps: PreparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(INSERT_SQL_PARAMS)

        configParams.forEachIndexed { index, it ->
            ps.setLong(1, it.configurationId)
            ps.setString(2, it.pKey)
            ps.setString(3, it.pValue)
            ps.addBatch()

            if (index != 0 && index % 1000 == 0) {
                ps.executeBatch()
                connection.commit()
            }
        }

        ps.executeBatch()
        connection.commit()
        ps
    }
}
```

And when i am looking at the logs using datasource proxy in spring boot, i can see actual queries that are executed.

So when i want to insert for example 2 items at once i see this in log:

```
Batch: True, INSERT INTO item_param(item_id, p_key, p_value) values (1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2)
Batch: False, INSERT INTO item_param(item_id, p_key, p_value) values ()
```

So as you can see i always at the end see that one extra/spare statement without any values, and from some reason log says Batch = False.

Can anyone see something that i am missing in my code, why is this happening and what i can do with this ?

Also i have one more question, for example if i have 1000 records, i will execute batch 2 times, one in if statement and one at the end. Is there some way where i can say ps.executeBatch only if there are params in query ?

Comment: Your code has a small bug when inserting exactly 1000/2000/3000/... items. The `ps.executeBatch()` will run once inside the loop, and then once again outside the loop with an empty batch. Is this the case you are debugging?

Comment: I actually suspected that and i tested this with inserting 3 items, so it never enters in that if statement. But again i have extra insert call...

I actually updated question with that case, do you have suggestion how i can execute query only if there are some params in query ?

Comment: keep an additional boolean, set it to true upon `addBatch` and to false upon `executeBatch` ?

Comment: Side note - if your application is heavy on inserts and batches aren't fast enough, you should try bulk inserting a CSV. It's quite faster than batches.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, yes that should do the trick with keeping boolean upon add batch! 

And yea i know that "trick" with CSV, but batches should be fine, its not like that i will work with millions of inserts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `jdbcTemplate.update` executes your SQL for you, so it automatically calls `execute` at the end of your code.

Since it calls `execute` exactly once, it doesn't fit your purposes. Try this [tutorial](https://www.roytuts.com/batch-insert-using-spring-jdbctemplate/) that uses `jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate`. It implements the multiple calls to `jdbcConnection` for you.